# Javascript throwing error when I've given custom file path

Tags: javascript, csv, filepath

I'm very new to JS. I have Html markup like this:

```
<label for="myfile">Select a CSV file:</label><br>
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" class="file-select" accept="text/csv">
```

What's happening here is I'm allowing user to select CSV files & storing them in an object called `myfile` .

In JS

```
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0];

console.log(selectedFile.name);
  this.fileName = selectedFile.name;
  Papa.parse(selectedFile, {
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    preview: readRange.numRows > 0 ? readRange.numRows : 0,
    complete: (results) => {
      console.log('Finished:', results.data);
      this.raw = results.data;
      this.limitColumns(readRange.numCols > 0 ? readRange.numCols : 0);
      this.header = Array.from(this.raw[0]); // problem: duplicated / null headers
      this.header.shift();
      this.refreshPreview();
      this.completed = true;
      console.log(this.completed);
```

verifying path

```
myfile.value
'C:\\fakepath\\r.csv'
```

Fakepath???

So I'm using `myfile` variable from Html & doing some operations on that CSV file..Upto know It's fine...**So my requirement is without changing the source I re assigned my custom file path in Js to `myfile` variable. like**

```
const mynewfile = "r.csv"
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('mynewfile').files[0];


console.log(selectedFile.name);
  this.fileName = selectedFile.name;
  Papa.parse(selectedFile, {
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    preview: readRange.numRows > 0 ? readRange.numRows : 0,
    complete: (results) => {
      console.log('Finished:', results.data);
      this.raw = results.data;
      this.limitColumns(readRange.numCols > 0 ? readRange.numCols : 0);
      this.header = Array.from(this.raw[0]); // problem: duplicated / null headers
      this.header.shift();
      this.refreshPreview();
      this.completed = true;
      console.log(this.completed);
```

So what I've done here is created a new variable & assigned my custom csv in order to test. But I get an error:

> vue.js:590 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')"
>
> (found in )

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

> Fakepath???

Browsers do not expose information about the structure of the visitor's file system to JavaScript running in web pages that they visit.

---

> ```
> const mynewfile = "r.csv"
> const selectedFile = document.getElementById('mynewfile').files[0];
> ```

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')"

The error message means that `document.getElementById('mynewfile')` returns `null` because there is no element with the ID `mynewfile`.

Possibly you were trying to use the variable `mynewfile` (since you defined it on the previous line but never use it) instead of the string literal `'mynewfile'`, but that won't work either — a file name is not the same as the ID you have given to your `<input>` element earlier in the page.

---

There is no way for you, as the author of a webpage, to tell the browser (belonging to the visitor) to read a file your your choice from your visitor's disk.

That would be a major security problem.

The visitor must pick the file from a file input.

Comment: hey hi @quentin...I've the complete source code...so according to your answer their is no id called `mynewfile`...so what "ve done is instead taking new variable I've took same var like `newfile` & assigned some custom path like  `const newfile = "r.csv"` ...so same var right I'm overwriting the path user selected before..But, still same error

Comment: @Bharth — I repeat: There is no way for you, as the author of a webpage, to tell the browser (belonging to the visitor) to read a file your your choice from your visitor's disk.

Comment: HI this is not final version...I was just checking with my own inputs out of curiosity ...My next step I've to import csv file from database...So just checking If I able to read the file with hard coded input then I was thinking to place this database variable inplace of that

Comment: No. There is no way for you, as the author of a webpage, to tell the browser (belonging to the visitor) to read a file your your choice from your visitor's disk

Comment: Ok @quentin forget about JS Is that possible to hardcode costume csv  in html itself?..Like initializing some path to `myfile` in html itself?

Comment: You could embed the CSV data as a string, but then you might as well express it as JS object/array literals in the first place. There is no way for you, as the author of a webpage, to tell the browser (belonging to the visitor) to read a file your your choice (i.e. specify the path) from your visitor's disk.

Comment: Hi @quentin thank you for your time!...i've finally reached my requirement...What i've done I've upload my csv to Aws s3 bucket & from there I've called whatever files required by API :)...You are true JS don't allow to give own user inputs from local desk .